# HTML Float Property Side by Side

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS and I produced this code regarding the `float` property.

```css
 

body {
    width: 750px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #665544;
}

p {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Using Float to Place Elements Side-by-Side</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>The Evolution of the Bicycle</h1>
  <p id="one">In 1817 Baron von Drais invented a walking machine that would help him get around the royal gardens faster.</p>
  <p id="two">The device know as the Draisienne (or "hobby horse") was made of wood, and propelled by pushing your feed on the ground in a gliding movement.</p>
  <p id="three">It was not seen a suitable for any place other than a well maintained pathway. </p>
  <p id="four">In 1865, the velocipede (meaning "fast foot") attached pedals to the front wheel, but its wooden structure made it extremely uncomfortable. </p>
  <p id="five">In 1870 the first all-metal machine appeared. The pedals were attached directly to the front wheel. 
  <p id="six">Solid rubber tires and the long spokes of the large front wheel provided a much smoother ride than its predecessor.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now, my question is this -

***Why does the fourth paragraph `id="four"` come under the third paragraph `id="three"` rather than moving to the left hand edge?***

Comment: Because they are "floated" and the 4th element has enough space to float left...

Answer (score 0):

`float: left;` will use every bit of free space available to make sure no space is wasted. You can see this in your example. The 3rd column has free space below, so the 4th column places itself there.

I think you're looking for `display: inline-block;` with a `vetical-align: top;` instead of a `float: left;` for a nice result. See the example below.

```css
   body {
    width: 750px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #665544;
   }
   p {
    width: 230px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Using Float to Place Elements Side-by-Side</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>The Evolution of the Bicycle</h1>
  <p id="one">In 1817 Baron von Drais invented a walking machine that would help him get around the royal gardens faster.</p>
  <p id="two">The device know as the Draisienne (or "hobby horse") was made of wood, and propelled by pushing your feed on the ground in a gliding movement.</p>
  <p id="three">It was not seen a suitable for any place other than a well maintained pathway. </p>
  <p id="four">In 1865, the velocipede (meaning "fast foot") attached pedals to the front wheel, but its wooden structure made it extremely uncomfortable. </p>
  <p id="five">In 1870 the first all-metal machine appeared. The pedals were attached directly to the front wheel. 
  <p id="six">Solid rubber tires and the long spokes of the large front wheel provided a much smoother ride than its predecessor.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have the `clear` property specified. From MDN:

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them.

```css
 

body {
    width: 750px;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #665544;
}

p {
    width: 230px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

#four {
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Using Float to Place Elements Side-by-Side</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>The Evolution of the Bicycle</h1>
  <p id="one">In 1817 Baron von Drais invented a walking machine that would help him get around the royal gardens faster.</p>
  <p id="two">The device know as the Draisienne (or "hobby horse") was made of wood, and propelled by pushing your feed on the ground in a gliding movement.</p>
  <p id="three">It was not seen a suitable for any place other than a well maintained pathway. </p>
  <p id="four">In 1865, the velocipede (meaning "fast foot") attached pedals to the front wheel, but its wooden structure made it extremely uncomfortable. </p>
  <p id="five">In 1870 the first all-metal machine appeared. The pedals were attached directly to the front wheel. 
  <p id="six">Solid rubber tires and the long spokes of the large front wheel provided a much smoother ride than its predecessor.</p>
 </body>
</html>
```